# SPSS - Split file according to 3 string questions

Tags: filter, split, spss

I have data from a 2x2x3 experiment. For this dataset I have 3 manipulation questions. I created three embedded data fields in the survey for these questions with the labels "Correct" and "Wrong".

Now, I would like to split my file in four versions to see if answering the 3 manipulation questions has an influence on my outcome.

To capture the correct/ wrong manipulation questions (ResponseReason, Attribution, Measure), I tried to create a filter variable - without success.

My code for the filter variable:

```
Do
if (ResponseAttribution = "Correct" and ResponseMeasure = "Correct" and ResponseReason = "Correct").
  FilterVar = 3.
ELSE if ((ResponseAttribution = "Correct" and ResponseMeasure = "Correct") or (ResponseAttribution = "Correct" and ResponseReason = "Correct") or (ResponseMeasure = "Correct" and ResponseReason = "Correct")).
  FilterVar = 2. 
Else if ResponseAttribution = "Correct" or ResponseMeasure = "Correct" or ResponseReason = "Correct".
  FilterVar = 1.
else.
  FilterVar = 0.
end if.
EXECUTE.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
compute FilterVar = sum(ResponseAttribution="Correct", 
       ResponseMeasure="Correct", ResponseReason="Correct").
```

Alternatively you can create new variables and use them to calculate the filter as follows (this way will make it easier if you later want to make alterations to the filter based on other combinations):

```
recode ResponseAttribution ResponseMeasure ResponseReason (convert) ("Correct"=1) 
   into Att Msr Rsn.
compute FilterVar=sum(Att, Msr, Rsn).
```